# How to change the wordpress footer background color?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I was creating a website in wordpress. I am using lifeline webanine charity theme. The Header Style I am using is header with social icon.I was trying to change the both the background color of the top bar and footer from black to any other color. Can anyone help me out?
The Code of header and footer is given bellow

Header.php

```html
<?php $settings = get_option( SH_NAME ); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
  <?php echo ( sh_set( $settings, 'site_favicon' ) ) ? '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="' . sh_set( $settings, 'site_favicon' ) . '">' : ''; ?>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title> 
   <?php
   if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    echo get_bloginfo( 'name' );
   } else {
    wp_title( '' );
   }
   ?>
        </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/ie.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
  <?php wp_head(); ?>

    </head>
 <?php
 $res_settings = sh_header_settings( $settings );
 $custom_sticky_header_class = (sh_set( $settings, 'sh_custom_stickey_menu' ) == 'true') ? 'sticky' : '';
 ?>
    <body <?php body_class( sh_set( $res_settings, 'pattern' ) ); ?> style=" <?php echo sh_set( $res_settings, 'pattern_image' ); ?>">
  <?php echo donation_box(); ?>
        <div class="theme-layout <?php
  if ( sh_set( $settings, 'boxed_layout_status' ) == 'true' ): echo 'boxed';
  endif;
  ?>" style=" <?php echo sh_set( $res_settings, 'width' ); ?>">
            <div id="top-bar">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul>
      <?php echo ( sh_set( $settings, 'header_address' ) ) ? '<li><i class="icon-home"></i>' . sh_set( $settings, 'header_address' ) . '</li>' : ''; ?>
      <?php echo ( sh_set( $settings, 'header_phone_number' ) ) ? '<li><i class="icon-phone"></i><a href="' . esc_url( sh_set( $settings, 'header_phone_number_link' ) ) . '" title="">' . sh_set( $settings, 'header_phone_number' ) . '</a></li>' : ''; ?>
      <?php echo ( sh_set( $settings, 'header_email_address' ) ) ? '<li><i class="icon-envelope"></i><a href="' . esc_url( sh_set( $settings, 'header_email_link' ) ) . '" title="">' . sh_set( $settings, 'header_email_address' ) . '</a></li>' : ''; ?>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="search-box">
                        <form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" method="GET">
                            <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="" >
                            <input class="search-input" type="text" name="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search', SH_NAME ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--top bar-->

            <header class="default-header <?php echo $custom_sticky_header_class; ?>">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="logo"> 
      <?php
      if ( sh_set( $settings, 'logo_text_status' ) === 'true' ) {
       $LogoStyle = sh_get_font_settings(
         array( 'logo_text_font_size' => 'font-size',
        'logo_text_font_family' => 'font-family',
        'logo_text_font_style' => 'font-style',
        'logo_text_color' => 'color' ), ' style="', '"' );
       $Logo = $settings['logo_text'];
      } else {
       $LogoStyle = '';
       $LogoImageStyle = ( sh_set( $settings, 'logo_width' ) || sh_set( $settings, 'logo_height' ) ) ? ' style="' : '';
       $LogoImageStyle .= ( sh_set( $settings, 'logo_width' ) ) ? ' width:' . sh_set( $settings, 'logo_width' ) . 'px;' : '';
       $LogoImageStyle .= ( sh_set( $settings, 'logo_height' ) ) ? ' height:' . sh_set( $settings, 'logo_height' ) . 'px;' : '';
       $LogoImageStyle .= ( sh_set( $settings, 'logo_width' ) || sh_set( $settings, 'logo_height' ) ) ? '"' : '';
       $Logo = '<img src="' . sh_set( $settings, 'logo_image' ) . '" alt=""' . $LogoImageStyle . ' />';
      }
      ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"<?php echo $LogoStyle; ?>>
       <?php if ( sh_set( $settings, 'logo_text_status' ) === 'true' )  ?> <h1 <?php echo $LogoStyle; ?>>
        <?php echo $Logo; ?>
        <?php if ( sh_set( $settings, 'logo_text_status' ) === 'true' )  ?> </h1>
                        </a>
      <?php
      if ( sh_set( $settings, 'logo_text_status' ) === 'true' && sh_set( $settings, 'site_salogan' ) ) {
       $SaloganStyle = sh_get_font_settings( array( 'salogan_font_size' => 'font-size', 'salogan_font_family' => 'font-family', 'salogan_font_style' => 'font-style' ), ' style="', '"' );
       echo '<p' . $SaloganStyle . '>' . sh_set( $settings, 'site_salogan' ) . '</p>';
      }
      ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <nav class="menu">
      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 'menu_class' => '', 'container' => null, 'menu_id' => 'menu-navigation', 'fallback_cb' => false, 'walker' => new SH_Megamenu_walker ) ); ?>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
   <?php sh_responsive_menu() ?> 
            <!--header-->
```

Footer.php

```html
</div>
<?php
$settings = get_option( SH_NAME );

if ( sh_set( $settings, 'show_footer' ) == 'true' ):

 $FooterStyle = ' style="';
 $FooterStyle .= ( isset( $settings['footer_font_family'] ) && !empty( $settings['footer_font_family'] ) ) ? 'font-family:' . $settings['footer_font_family'] . ';' : '';
 $FooterStyle .= ( sh_set( $settings, 'footer_bg' ) ) ? 'background-image:url(' . sh_set( $settings, 'footer_bg' ) . ');' : '';
 $FooterStyle .= '"';
 ?>

 <footer<?php echo $FooterStyle; ?>>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-sidebar' ); ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </footer>

 <?php
endif;
?>



<div class="footer-bottom">

    <div class="container">

        <p><?php echo stripslashes( sh_set( $settings, 'footer_copyright' ) ); ?><span> All Rights Reserved.</span> </p>

  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-right' ); ?>

    </div>

</div>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">Stripe.setPublishableKey('<?php echo STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY; ?>');</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead with CSS. Take the class name of outer div in header and footer then give the appropriate color. Or just reply your code of header and footer.php

Comment: As the code is too large to add in the reply section,I have added it in the post.....TIA